# Update in Before Delete Trigger instead of deleting them shows strange behavior

Tags: before-trigger, delete

I am working on a use case in which I have to update records instead of deleting them when deleting them.

As per my understanding, we cannot achieve this easily without undeleting the same records. What I've tried is undeleting the records and update it back by calling an Queueable Apex.

I've seen a strange behavior as when I pass the List to a Queueable Apex it throws me a 'Record is read-only' error, it deletes the records and didn't restore it from recycle bin (The undelete is not working). However, when I passed as String it works perfectly fine with what I've expected.

What I've missed over there?

Trigger,

```
public with sharing class DeletePortfolioTriggerHandler {

    if (Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isBefore) {
        System.enqueueJob(new SP_Core_PorfolioAndChildQueueable((List<sp_core__Portfolio__c>) Trigger.old));
    }
}
```

```
    public with sharing class PorfolioAndChildQueueable implements Queueable {

        List<Portfolio__c> lstPortfolio;

        public PorfolioAndChildQueueable(List<Portfolio__c> lstPortfolio) {
            this.lstPortfolio = lstPortfolio;
        }

        public void execute(QueueableContext qc) {

            undelete lstPortfolio;

            System.debug('Portfolio Records ' + lstPortfolio.size());

            for(Portfolio__c portfolio : lstPortfolio) {

                portfolio.IsDeleted__c = true;
            }

            if (lstPortfolio.size() > 0) {
                SObjectAccessDecision securityDecision = Security.stripInaccessible(
                    AccessType.UPDATABLE,
                    lstPortfolio
                );

            update securityDecision.getRecords();
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code has deleted the records and gave an error as 'Record is read-only' in the Queueable debug.

When I modify the code as below it works perfectly fine,

```
public with sharing class DeletePortfolioTriggerHandler {

    if (Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isBefore) {
        System.enqueueJob(new SP_Core_PorfolioAndChildQueueable(JSON.serialize((List<sp_core__Portfolio__c>) Trigger.old)));
    }
}
```

```
public with sharing class PorfolioAndChildQueueable implements Queueable {

    String portfolioJSON;

    public PorfolioAndChildQueueable(String portfolioJSON;) {
        this.portfolioJSON = portfolioJSON;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext qc) {

        List<sp_core__Portfolio__c> lstPortfolio =(List<sp_core__Portfolio__c> ) JSON.deserialize(portfolioJSON, List<sp_core__Portfolio__c>.class);
        
        undelete lstPortfolio;

        System.debug('Portfolio Records ' + lstPortfolio.size());

        for(Portfolio__c portfolio : lstPortfolio) {

            portfolio.IsDeleted__c = true;
        }

        if (lstPortfolio.size() > 0) {
            SObjectAccessDecision securityDecision = Security.stripInaccessible(
                AccessType.UPDATABLE,
                lstPortfolio
            );

            update securityDecision.getRecords();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of dealing with delete / undelete, have you considered removing the Delete permission from profiles, then overriding the Delete button with your custom update process?

Comment: Yes tried it as well. But my question is different here. Why I have two different behaviors when using two different type as explained above?

Comment: @sfdcfox, Any comment on this behavior?